# How to get City and Country from Android Place picker?

Tags: android, google-places-api

Please help. I try to implement Place picker to get City name and Country. but it still no result.

In NewItemFragment

```
  mAddLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //TODO QIBEE Insert
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(getActivity());
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

in App.java

```
  Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {

                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                    App.getInstance().setLat(latitude);
                    App.getInstance().setLng(longitude);

                    sharedPref.edit().putString(getString(R.string.settings_account_lat), Double.toString(this.getLat())).apply();
                    sharedPref.edit().putString(getString(R.string.settings_account_lng), Double.toString(this.getLng())).apply();

                    App.getInstance().setArea(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
                    App.getInstance().setCity(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    App.getInstance().setCountry(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried till now so that we can help a little.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to change something into your code. But you didn't show it, so that's all we can help with.

Answer (score 3):

you will get longditute and latitiude from onActivityResult and call this function getAddress with parameters latitiude and longditute

```
public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();
        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: dont use String concatination  or "+" because doing so will create new instance of String evry time. which is not good use **StringBuilder** instead.

Answer (score -1):

`PlaceAutocompleteFragment` to an `activity`, add a new fragment named `com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment` to an XML layout.

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
  />
```

Add a `PlaceSelectionListener` to an `activity`

The `PlaceSelectionListener` handles returning a place in response to the user's selection. The following code shows creating a reference to the `fragment` and adding a `listener` to your `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
  });
```